# Is $\left|\frac{d\vec{r}}{dt}\right| = \frac{d|\vec{r}|}{dt}\;$?

Tags: kinematics, velocity, vectors

Is magnitude of instantaneous velocity same as instantaneous speed?

More specifically, is $$\left|\frac{d\vec{r}}{dt}\right| = \frac{d|\vec{r}|}{dt}\; $$

Also **Is it wrong to say that $\dfrac{d|\vec{v}|}{dt}$ is rate of change of speed?**

Comment: The LHS is a scalar measure of the rate of change of the position vector, whereas the RHS is a measure of the rate of change of the distance from the origin. As an example, it should be easy to see that any circular trajectory $\textbf{r}(t)$ should violate the equality.

Comment: Tim Krul: "_Is magnitude of velocity same as speed?_" -- If by "_speed_" you specificly mean the left term of your equation then **apparently you don't mean to distinguish** between "_speed_ on the journey before reaching" e.g. some particular "origin" of the description, and "_speed_ afterwards". However, the right term of your present equation, $$ \frac{d}{dt}[\| ~\vec r \|~], $$ makes this distinction; and some answers make a point of that. So consider asking instead about $$\left\lvert \left\lvert \frac{d}{dt}[~\vec r~] \right\rvert \right\rvert =?\!\!= \frac{d}{d|t|}[~\|\vec r\|~].$$

Comment: @user12262 what do you people mean by two moduli ?

Comment: Tim Krul: "_what do you people mean by two moduli ?_" -- The double bars which appeared in @diracpaul's answer and which I subsequently used as well (in comments and in editing my answer) is the notation for "[norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29)". I think that's more appropriate for denoting a distance value (which in geometry/physics usually has some dimension: "length") than using only single bars which denote "[modulus, or absolute value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value)" (which is just some non-negative real number).

Comment: @DavidZ does a great job of sorting out the confusion, but it would be great if the wording of the question could be fixed.  As it stands the question is "is magnitude of velocity same as speed?" to which the answer is yes by definition and is uninteresting; if your real question is whether $\left|\frac{d\vec{r}}{dt}\right| = \frac{d|\vec{r}|}{dt}$ then that is actually an interesting question, and it would be good to make your question (and first sentence) actually say that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually you're asking two different questions.

1. *Is the magnitude of instantaneous velocity the same as instantaneous speed?* Well, yes, that's the definition of instantaneous speed.
2. *Is this equation true?*
   $$\biggl\lvert\frac{\mathrm{d}\vec{r}}{\mathrm{d}t}\biggr\rvert = \frac{\mathrm{d}\lvert\vec{r}\rvert}{\mathrm{d}t}$$
   No, it's not - but instantaneous speed is the quantity on the *left*. The one on the right is the radial component of velocity in a circular coordinate system, and it is useful for some detailed calculations, but it's not one of the "basic" kinematic quantities (for most reasonable definitions of "basic").

   For fun: an example that shows the difference is uniform circular motion, where the quantity on the right is zero but the one on the left is not. Also note that the thing on the right can actually be negative, if the particle is getting closer to the origin over time.

Since $\vec{v} = \frac{\mathrm{d}\vec{r}}{\mathrm{d}t}$ by definition, the quantity on the left in the above equation is $\lvert\vec{v}\rvert$, and so $\frac{\mathrm{d}\lvert\vec{v}\rvert}{\mathrm{d}t}$ is the rate of change of speed.

Comment: I edited the question and added another branched question. Is that correct?

Comment: @TimKrul I've edited my answer accordingly. But keep in mind (for the future) that it's best not to edit extra questions into your post. Editing to clarify the questions you've already asked is fine, but when you have a new, separate question, it's best to make a separate post.

Comment: Very clear resolution of a confusing question.

Answer (score 6):

Your equation is not valid, see Figure below[image]

With equations

\begin{equation}
\Vert\mathbf{r}\Vert^{2}=\mathbf{r}\circ \mathbf{r} \Longrightarrow  2\cdot \Vert\mathbf{r}\Vert\cdot d\Vert\mathbf{r}\Vert =2\cdot\left(\mathbf{r}\circ d\mathbf{r}\right)\Longrightarrow d\Vert \mathbf{r}\Vert =\dfrac{\mathbf{r}}{\Vert\mathbf{r}\Vert}\circ d \mathbf{r}
\tag{01} 
\end{equation}
so
\begin{equation}
\bigl|d\Vert\mathbf{r}\Vert\bigr| \le \dfrac{\Vert\mathbf{r}\Vert}{\Vert\mathbf{r}\Vert}\cdot\Vert d \mathbf{r}\Vert =\Vert d \mathbf{r}\Vert
\tag{02} 
\end{equation}

[image]

Figure in "CLASSICAL MECHANICS" Herbert Goldstein-Charles Poole-John Safko, 3rd Edition 2000, Addison-Wesley (user12262)

Comment: diracpaul: The notation used in the sketch you provided can be confusing, because you use the symbol $d$ "by itself"; and apparently not as the OP, only within a pair $\frac{d}{d}$ for denoting a [derivative operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative). It seems advisable that your letters $d$ be replaced (individually) by the symbol $\Delta$; writing in particular $$\|\Delta\mathbf r\|\ne\Delta\|\mathbf r\|.$$ Also, please consider formatting and including your sketch by means of appropriate available MathJax commands for easier editing by us, the Physics Stackexchange contributors.

Comment: @user12262 The two positions of a moving particle in Figure are at a differential distance apart in a differential time interval $dt$. If you take $dt>0$ and divide the operator $d$ by $dt$ you have the desired one $d/dt$.

Comment: diracpaul: "_The two positions of a moving particle in Figure are at a differential distance apart_" -- Hmm ... A "[_differential_ (infinitesimal)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_%28infinitesimal%29) _distance_", $d$, i.e. [that there is no way to measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitesimal) "it"? Or instead a "_differential distance_", $\Delta$, which is still in the (physical) realm of "the measurable", characterizing a geometric relation between distinguishable "ends", commensurate to other (incl. "large") distance values? (Then we may consider ratios, and take limits.)

Comment: p.s. My request for making the given sketch editable is also driven by the desire to easily and unambiguously reference its salient ["graphic"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28mathematics%29) features (with even better resolution than to note the "color of the dots", because there seem to be several "dots" of the same color in the sketch as  presently provided). Especially: How would you call the blue "dot" by which the two red arrows are connected (and two of the black arrows happen to be connected, too)? And (perhaps more importantly): why did you draw these two red arrows at all?

Comment: diracpaul: Concerning the two equations (which had been added after I made my first comment), I'm struggling already to follow the equations and implications with tag "$(01)$". Is there perhaps a "$\lt$" sign missing somewhere? And is there perhaps a version of these equations and implications in terms of "differences $\Delta$" instead of "infinitesimals $d$", to provide at least some plausibility?

Comment: @user12262  (a)How do we differentiate an equation between finite variables ??? For example $y=x^2$ by differentiation yields $dy=2xdx$. What are then $dy, dx$ ??? That's differential calculus. In  (01) we differentiate the first to the left equation. Now, you prefer to look at this equation as derivative $dy/dx=2x$.(b) Equation (01) is as it is. There is no "<" sign missing.

Comment: @user12262 The Figure was created very quickly with "GeoGebra"(I found this software 2-3 days ago in StackExchange), and printed as image ".jpeg". Sorry, but I don't know how to create editable sketches with MathJax.

Comment: `1 (Re: the Figure)` diracpaul: "_What are then_ $dy,dx$ _???_" -- A pertinent question, deserving of a specific answer. But what I question specificly goes moreover to the consequence: **Is it therefore appropriate** to use "$d$" (rather than "$\Delta$") for labelling elements of your Figure, as it presently stands?!? "_Sorry, but I don't know how to create editable sketches with MathJax_" -- And I'm sorry, too: I don't know much more about that than to [google "MathJax" and "pstricks"](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=%22MathJax%22+%22pstricks%22). But **consider** the possibilities ...

Comment: `2 (Re: eq. (01))`  diracpaul: "_In (01) we differentiate the first equation._" -- Ah, thanks, that helps (me trying to follow your argument). So: How exactly would you argue in the particular case that $$\mathbf r \mapsto \mathbf{r_0},$$ where $$\|\mathbf{r_0}\|=0$$ ?? (Btw., this seems more or less the "subtlety" which I was concerned about in much of my own answer to the OP.) p.s. "$y=x^2$ _by differentiation yields_ $dy=2~x~dx$" -- I find it reassuring, and even necessary to know in the first place, that $$2~x=\text{lim}_{\{\Delta x\rightarrow 0\}}[\frac{(x+\Delta x)^2-x^2}{\Delta x}].$$

Comment: Can I know what is going on?

Comment: @user36790  Many thanks for all comments, approvals and support.  In 2-3 hours we can't contact  each other any more. Good Luck to your personal and scientific life.

Comment: @diracpaul: I am fearing you are going, is it? Hey, sir, don't go. You can still give many good answers! I am really not getting sense what is going. If you are going, I wish you a good life; thanks for being here. Please can you tell me how to contact you? Your email-id?? Please??

Answer (score 2):

Obviously not: think to a very simple (2d) example, $r(t)=(t,t)$.

Componentwise, the derivative yields $1,1$, and hence $\lvert dr/dt\rvert=\sqrt{2}$.

On the other hand, $\lvert r(t)\rvert = \sqrt{2}\lvert t \rvert$. And the absolute value function is not differentiable in zero.

Hence the two derivative functions coincide almost everywhere, but not in zero where the second does not exist.

Comment: I edited the question and added another branched question. Is that correct?

Comment: no its dv/dt in second question. Then is it correct?

Comment: @TimKrul Oh, what is $\nu$?

Comment: In second question it is velocity

Comment: yuggib: I've just suggested to the OP to ask instead about $$\left\lvert \left\lvert \frac{d}{dt}[~\vec r~] \right\rvert \right\rvert =?\!\!=  \frac{d}{d|t|}[~\|\vec r\|~].$$
(I wonder if that's going to happen. Or which title I would choose if I'd try to ask this question myself, eventually ...)

Answer (score 0):

> is $\left|\frac{d\vec{r}}{dt}\right| = \frac{d|\vec{r}|}{dt} $ [?]

There's a subtlety here ...
It depends on how (you want that) the right-hand side of your suggested equation is interpreted.

We know, of course, by to the [rigorous definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative#Rigorous_definition) of what [the notation you've used](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative#Leibniz.27s_notation) is supposed to mean, that the value of a derivative is evaluated "at" a particular value of the (variable) argument; e.g. "at a particular point $t_a$":

$$\left. \frac{d}{dt}[~\vec r] \right|_{t = t_a} := \text{lim}_{\{t \rightarrow t_a\}}\left[~\frac{\vec r[~t~] - \vec r[~t_a~] }{t - t_a}  ~\right].$$

(This, by itself, should be completely unambiguous; and therefore the left-hand side of your suggested equation, too.)

Now, it seems at least formally straight-forward to "take the magnitude" (as in the right-hand side of your suggested equation) and express explicitly:

$$\left. \frac{d}{dt}[~|\vec r|] \right|_{t = t_a} := \text{lim}_{\{t \rightarrow t_a\}}\left[~\frac{|\vec r[~t~]| - |\vec r[~t_a~]| }{t - t_a}  ~\right].$$

But there is a possible ambiguity of interpretation:

- Either: all vectors in the above formula are understood in reference to "the limit point" $\vec r[~t_a~]$, at least for the explicit purpose of evaluating the derivative specificly "at the point $t_a$".
  In this case, obviously, $|\vec r[~t_a~]| = 0$;
  and also (applicable to the left-hand side of your suggested equation) $|\vec r[~t~] - \vec r[~t_a~]| = |\vec r[~t~]|$;
  and in consequence your suggested equation holds<sup>(1)</sup> (separately for each individual "evaluation point $t_a$", and therefore overall, too) for any trajectory $\vec r[~t~]$ (if given by an "intrinsic description").
- Or: all vectors in the above formula are understood in reference a particular "origin" (e.g. $r_C$ as "center of the description"), regardless of any specific "evaluation point $t_a$", but fixed for evaluating the derivatives at any such points.
  In this case $\vec r[~t~] \equiv \vec r[~t~] - \vec r_C$;
  and $|\vec r[~t_a~] - \vec r_C|$ may or may not be equal to $|\vec r[~t_b~] - \vec r_C|$ for different "evaluation points" $t_a$ and $t_b$;
  and in consequence your suggested equation may fail (depending on the detailed trajectory $\vec r[~t~]$ and choice of "origin $r_C$"; with "circular motion in reference to the center" as basic counter-example).

p.s.

> [...] speed

Speed is unambiguously the magnitude of velocity; namely expressed by the left-hand side of your suggested equation.
Speed values being therefore necessarily non-negative, one can then distinguish (intrinsically):

- the (non-zero) speed in the limit approaching (towards) some particular evaluation point $t_a$, or
- the (non-zero) speed in the limit departing from some particular evaluation point $t_a$, or
- speed being zero at evaluation point $t_a$.

In reference to some (possibly external) fixed "origin $r_C$" one may also distinguish "radial speed" (corresponding to the suitably interpreted right-hand side of your suggested equation) and "angular speed".

**EDIT**

<sup>(1): At least up to a sign, which would signify a distinction between "*speed* on the journey before reaching $\vec r[~t_a~]$", and "*speed* afterwards". However, it seems also questionable whether such a distinction is even intended at all. Accordingly it seems even more appropriate to investigate whether $$ \left\lvert \left\lvert \frac{d}{dt}[~\vec r~] \right\rvert \right\rvert =?\!\!= \frac{d}{d|t|}[~\|\vec r\|~].$$</sup>

Comment: Thank you for a nice explanation! but i wanted to ask what does double modulus mean? and what does square bracket signify?

Comment: @Tim Krul: "_what does double modulus mean?_" -- That's the notation for "[norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29)". (Having seen this in diracpaul's answer I find it more appropriate than "[modulus, or absolute value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value)".) "_what does square bracket signify?_" -- In square brackets I usually enclose [arguments to functions, or operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_of_a_function); here e.g. the argument to which the differential operator is applied. (That's "Mathematica style"; reserving parentheses for grouping only).