# Difference between $|d{\bf r}|$ and $d|{\bf r}|$

Tags: kinematics, velocity, vectors, notation, differentiation

What is the difference between $|d{\bf r}|$ and $d|{\bf r}|$ and why are both of them not always equal to each other?
My question might seem stupid to some and will probably get downvoted but I have thought on the question but still can't comprehend any difference between the two.
I was reading Irodov's Mechanics as an extra reading,when I came upon this!
The book has given an example at the footnote but I  still can't understand. :/
[image: The book has given an example at the footnote but I can't understand still. :/]

Comment: See my answer there :http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/191296/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in the diagram $|dr|$ represents the magnitude of the vector difference(that involves the laws of vector addition/subtraction) between $\vec{r_2}\quad \& \quad  \vec{r_1}$ while $d|r|$ represents the difference between magnitudes of two vectors which is simply the difference in their lengths.

Answer (score 1):

Using polar coordinates it holds $ |d{\bf r}| = \sqrt{(d|{\bf r}|)^2 + |{\bf r}|^2(d{\bf \phi})^2}$. From this equation you can see, the two expressions you are asking about are actually only equal (in absolute value) for a straight line through the origin, thus otherwise different. For them to be exactly equal, the $d|{\bf r}|$ should be moreover pointing away from the origin (i.e., positive).

Answer (score 1):

If
$$
\overrightarrow{r}=r_{x}\widehat{i}+r_{y}\widehat{j}
$$
then
$$
\left | \overrightarrow{r} \right |=\sqrt{r_{x}^{2}+r_{y}^{2}}
$$
and
$$
d\left | \overrightarrow{r} \right |=\frac{r_{x}dr_{x}+r_{y}dr_{y}}{\sqrt{r_{x}^{2}+r_{y}^{2}}}
$$
on the other hand
$$
d\overrightarrow{r}=dr_{x}\widehat{i}+dr_{y}\widehat{j}
$$
and
$$
\left | d\overrightarrow{r} \right |=\sqrt{dr_{x}^{2}+dr_{y}^{2}}
$$