# Why is $ds$ used to mean the magnitude of $d\textbf{s}$ in general relativity when $ds=d\lvert \textbf{s}\rvert\neq\lvert d\textbf{s}\rvert$?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, definition, notation, calculus

Why is $ds$, the line element, often used to mean the magnitude of $d\textbf{s}$ in general relativity when $ ds = d \lvert \textbf{s} \rvert \neq \lvert d\textbf{s} \rvert $? The magnitude of an infinitesimal displacement is not in general equal to the infinitesimal magnitude of a displacement, e.g. in circular motion, where the size of displacement does not change at all but the infinitesimal change of displacement is due to the change of direction only.

Comment: What does $d|\mathbf{s}|$ mean? The notation seems to imply you think there is a function $\mathbf{s}$ that we are differentiating. In differential geometry you have to be careful that a vector is only defined in the tangent space of a point; there is no "position vector" like there is in Euclidean geometry. I typically think of $d\mathbf{s}$ as being an infintesimal displacement in the tangent space. So I'd be inclined to say $ds=|d\mathbf{s}|$, and $d|\mathbf{s}|$ is meaningless. But this is heuristic; rigorously $ds^2$ is just short hand for the metric tensor.

Comment: Related : [Is $\left|\frac{d\vec{r}}{dt}\right| = \frac{d|\vec{r}|}{dt}$?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/191296/is-left-fracd-vecrdt-right-fracd-vecrdt?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the comments, $\mathbf s$ is in general kinda meaningless. But the claim in OP is not true even in Euclidean space.

Let $\mathbf r=(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in\mathbb R^n$ and let $\mathbb R^n$ be equipped with the flat Euclidean (positive definite) metric.

Then $ds^2$ can be taken to be $ds^2=d\mathbf r\cdot d\mathbf r=|d\mathbf r|^2$ since the latter is $d\mathbf r\cdot d\mathbf r=dx^2_1+dx_2^2+\dots +dx^2_n$ which is of course the standard line element.

On the other hand $|\mathbf r|=(x_1^2+\dots x_n^2)^{1/2}$ so $$ d|\mathbf r|=\frac{x_1 dx_1+\dots+x_n dx_n}{(x_1^2+\dots+x_n^2)^{1/2}}=\frac{\mathbf r\cdot d\mathbf r}{|\mathbf r|}\neq (dx_1^2+\dots+dx^2_n)^{1/2}=ds. $$

So, $ds$ is always $|d\mathbf r|$ (the magnitude of an elementary displacement) rather than $d|\mathbf r|$ which in general does not even make sense (on a general manifold there is no $\mathbf r$).

Comment: My objection is that $ds$ is used to mean an elementary distance and $d\textbf{s}$ is used to mean an elementary displacement, when in vector analysis the convention is that $s = \lvert \textbf{s} \rvert$. You are fine because you called the distance $ds$ and the displacement $d\textbf{r}$